# Have to save data in list array[ ]. first check two list array intersect them and give the remaining values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

```cs
var data = db.User_Register_Events.Where(x => x.UserTable.User_id == "Rehman").Select(x => x.EventTable.Slot.Slot_Id).ToList();           

var data2 = db.User_Register_Events.Where(x => x.UserTable.User_id == "Muhammad").Select(x => x.EventTable.Slot.Slot_Id).ToList();

List<int> data3 = data.Concat(data2).ToList();
List<Slot> AllSlots = db.Slots.Where(x => x.Slot_Id > 1).ToList();
```

What query should I write to first compare the in (`data3`) and (`AllSlots`), and then pass the unmatched values from `AllSlots` to Array List view?

I tried this, but it's not a valid solution:

```cs
List<string> intersect = AllSlots.Except(data3).ToAray();
```

---

---

See the variable data which has data (eg, 11,12,13,24,55), these are basically slot IDs as you can see in the database schema.
The second variable data2 stores (11,33,52,13,23)

Both data and data2 are stored in list:

```cs
List<int> data3 = data.Concat(data2).ToList();
```

There is another List which is storing all the ("SLOT IDs"):

> (11,12,13,14,15,16,21,22,23,24,25,26.............51,52,53,53,55,56)

```cs
List<Slot> AllSlots = db.Slots.Where(x => x.Slot_Id > 1).ToList();
```

What I want is...
I have to work on ("data3") and ("AllSlots")

I have to check/print all the values in ("AllSlots") list, EXCEPT data3 values...

Comment: Don't need the `ToList`s by the way

Comment: If you say you need an intersect why do you never use Enumerable.Intersect?

Comment: The method is `ToArray()` not `ToAray()`...

Comment: It can be soleved in one query but we need model classes of  `User_Register_Events` and `Slots`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your edit it now looks like you want:

```
allSlots.Except(data1.Union(data2));
```

If the complaint is that it's not working because allslots stores Slot objects and `data1.Union(data2)` is a list of ints, you can do:

```
allSlots.Where(s => !data1.Contains(s.Slot_Id) && !data2.Contains(s.Slot_Id));
```

You don't need data3. If you have thousands of things in allSlots, data1 or data2 it would be more performant to use a HashSet for the Contains but for some low tens of entries in each this will suffice

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are actually wanting the disjunction (everything from data1 that isn't in data2 and everything from data2 that isn't in data1). HashSet has a useful function for that:

```
new HashSet<int>(data1).SymmetricExceptWith(data2);
```

For a data1 of {1,2} and a data2 of {2,3} the hashset has {1,3}

Comment: i have update the post please recheck. so the scenario get more clear